# apache-calculating ServerLimit based on buff/cache, available memory? or both?

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, mpm-event

I have been reading many articles to understand how to configure apache server for a high traffic website. the article [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-performance-tuning-swap-memory/) tries to calculate Thrashing point-where swapping occurs-and then calculates an initial estimate for the number of `ServerLimit` parameter for `mpm_event` based on that:

```
Thrashing Point=(buff/cache - reserved)/(Avg. Apache)
```

in the Buff/Cache Memory section of the article, the writer says:

> Don’t be fooled by the column labeled “available.” We are solely looking at the memory we can reappropriate, which is the buff/cache column

this is what confuses me. in the article example, there is about 700 MB of buffer/cache and about 700 MB of available memory, but only the 700 MB of buffere/cache is taken into account for calculating the maximum number of apache children (`ServerLimit`). my question is that why the remained 700 MB of available memory is not considered while it is large and unused, and if taken into account can increase `ServerLimit` significantly?!

Comment: I can't find numbers like that in the article you linked to. Did you also read some other article?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, the numbers were in MB not GB (you can find them in the shell screenshot in the article). I have read some other articles but not all of them follow the same approach and it's confusing. I would be grateful if you would share me your suggestion-if you have one.

Comment: I'm not following something here. The article you linked to has `free` output showing buff/cache is 708436 and available is 731680. If you used 700 MiB for a program, there would be only about 30 MiB available. Where are you getting the extra 700 MiB from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton now it seems I have misunderstood how buff/cached and available memory are defined. I thought they are separate from each other and don't have anything in common. but based on your comment I think I'm wrong. right?!